# Comparnig two curves with the same shape but shifted along an axis

Tags: python, compare, data-science, shapes, dtw

I am trying to compare two curves that have exactly the same shape, but are shifted along the x-axis. For this problem I am using dtw (dynamic time warping) since it shouldn't be susceptible to shifting, or stretching. Please have a look at following example code:

```
x=np.linspace(0,10,9)         #creating points on the x-axis
y=np.random.randint(0,10,9)   #random values for y
x2=x+4                        #manual shift along x

exp_data = np.zeros((len(x), 2))
exp_data[:, 0] = x
exp_data[:, 1] = y
    
num_data = np.zeros((len(x), 2))
num_data[:, 0] = x2
num_data[:, 1] = y 

import similaritymeasures as sim
dtw,d=sim.dtw(exp_data,num_data)
```

I would expect the result of dtw to be 0, but get a value greater than 0 instead and therefore would think they are not very alike.
Am I interpreting the result incorrectly? Is there a better way to measure the similarity of shapes that is not susceptible to shifting/stretching?

Comment: How big result do you get ? Computer can't keep every float number and it keeps aproximation - so `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` gives `False` - and then result can be little different then `0` and you should use some small value to check similarity ie. `if -0.01 < dtw < 0.01: print("the same")`

Comment: Thanks for your replay @furas Not sure if I understand your question correct, but if I use the code I plotted and compare the two curves that were randomly created (see my results below) I get:
`y=([1, 4, 9, 1, 5, 7, 1, 0, 3])`
`x=([ 0.  ,  1.25,  2.5 ,  3.75,  5.  ,  6.25,  7.5 ,  8.75, 10.  ])`
`x2=([ 4.  ,  5.25,  6.5 ,  7.75,  9.  , 10.25, 11.5 , 12.75, 14.  ])`
and respectively a dtw of 
`dtw=36.0`

Comment: I run your code with different values `x+4`,`x+1`, etc. and `dtw` gives me value which I can get also with simple `(x-x2).sum()` - so this `dtw` only sums differences between points. Better result gives me `diff = x-x2`, `(diff - diff.min()).sum()`  because it gives me `0` but maybe it could be good to use `average` instead of `minimal` value.